# Maximum devices can be tested with appium using selenium grid?

Tags: android, selenium, appium, android-testing, selenium-grid

I am testing android app using  30 devices parallelly. I am using Appium with selenium grid. My computer freezes when 30 devices are tested at once. Can you help me to scale up to 40 devices.
My setup : Windows 10 with Intel i5 CPU, 16 GB RAM.
Java Appium client, selenium grid with 30 android devices

Comment: Can you share your _Test Setup_ and code trials?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask